# Apply function over data.frame values

Tags: r, dplyr

I've been stumbling around over something I feel I should know. Given a small data.frame, say:

```
d <- tibble(a = c(45, 1, 2, 9), b = c(3, 19, 8, 12))

> d
# A tibble: 4 x 2
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1    45     3
2     1    19
3     2     8
4     9    12
```

I'd like to mutate some new variables with the result of a call to toOrdinal (from the toOrdinal library). I tried this:

```
d %>% mutate(
  across(everything(), ~ toOrdinal::toOrdinal(.x), .names = "ord_{col}")
)
```

But the results aren't right:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
      a     b ord_a ord_b
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1    45     3 45th  3rd  
2     1    19 1th   19rd 
3     2     8 2th   8rd  
4     9    12 9th   12rd
```

Instead, what I'd like to see is:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
      a     b ord_a ord_b
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1    45     3 45th  3rd  
2     1    19 1st   19th 
3     2     8 2nd   8th  
4     9    12 9th   12th
```

The `warnings()`, which are usually pretty helpful, aren't pointing me to what exactly I'm doing wrong.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is not `Vectorized`.  Either we use `rowwise` or `Vectorize` the function

```
library(dplyr)
library(toOrdinal)
d %>% 
    mutate(across(everything(), ~  Vectorize(toOrdinal)(.),.names = "ord_{col}"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#      a     b ord_a ord_b
#  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#1    45     3 45th  3rd  
#2     1    19 1st   19th 
#3     2     8 2nd   8th  
#4     9    12 9th   12th
```

---

Or use `rowwise`

```
d %>%
   rowwise() %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), ~ toOrdinal(.), .names = "ord_{col}")) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#      a     b ord_a ord_b
#  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#1    45     3 45th  3rd  
#2     1    19 1st   19th 
#3     2     8 2nd   8th  
#4     9    12 9th   12th
```

---

Or another option is to do the rowwise with `pmap` from `purrr` and bind the output tibble with the original dataset

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
pmap_dfr(d, ~  map_dfr(list(...), toOrdinal)) %>% 
   rename_all(~ str_c('ord_', .)) %>%
   bind_cols(d, .)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#      a     b ord_a ord_b
#  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#1    45     3 45th  3rd  
#2     1    19 1st   19th 
#3     2     8 2nd   8th  
#4     9    12 9th   12th
```

Comment: Ah, yes. Thank you! I'd read about rowwise() but hadn't put it into practice. Makes great sense. Thank you again.